# How to use data binding for radio buttons in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, radio-button

How can I use data binding for radio buttons in windows phone 8?

My radio buttons

```
<RadioButton Content="5" GroupName="Radius" IsChecked="true" />
<RadioButton Content="10" GroupName="Radius" IsChecked="true" />
<RadioButton Content="20" GroupName="Radius" IsChecked="true" />
<RadioButton Content="50" GroupName="Radius" IsChecked="true" />
<RadioButton Content="All" GroupName="Radius" IsChecked="true" />
```

(If you note that I am answering this question myself, you are right. I had a lot of trouble finding the working solution. Problem is, that some features missing on windows phone. For example `Binding.DoNothing`, which works on other platforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create DataContext and bind it to your `PhoneApplicationPage`. It looks like this

`DataContext="{Binding Search, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`

This is usual binding and there are plenty of good tutorials, so I will not explain this here.

Then in your DataContext, you create properties that reflect your radio buttons.

```
    private int _radiusRadio;
    public int RadiusRadio
    {
        get
        {
            return _radiusRadio;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != -1)
            {
                if (Set(() => RadiusRadio, ref _radiusRadio, value))
                {
                    IsDirty = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In _radiusRadio is stored the chosen value. I am using framework `MVVM light`, I recommend it too, that why I am setting that IsDirty property there. Otherwise, you should implement "classic" `NotifyChanging` and `NotifyChanged` event as usual.

The only difference here is, that if you are setting the value to -1, you do nothing. This is because of weird behaviour of windows-phone when selecting radio button. It works without it when you run your app and access page with radio buttons first time. But when you leave that page and return, it starts to send values you do not expect.

Now we are ready to create our Convertor. Convertor is also a typical thing for data binding in windos phone.

Here is code for the convertor (you can copy and paste it, it is same for any set of radio buttons)

```
public class RadioButtonConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int index = (int)value;
        int parIndex = Int32.Parse((string)parameter);
        return index == parIndex;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null || (bool)value == false)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return Int32.Parse((string)parameter);   
    }
}
```

To add converters, you have to add this

`xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyGreatApp.Converters"` to the `PhoneApplicationPage`

and then define concrete Converter

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <converters:RadioButtonConverter x:Key="Radius" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Now you are ready to use data binding >

```
<RadioButton Content="5" GroupName="Radius" IsChecked="{Binding RadiusRadio, Converter={StaticResource Radius}, ConverterParameter=1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<RadioButton Content="10" GroupName="Radius" IsChecked="{Binding RadiusRadio, Converter={StaticResource Radius}, ConverterParameter=2, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
<RadioButton Content="20" GroupName="Radius"  IsChecked="{Binding RadiusRadio, Converter={StaticResource Radius}, ConverterParameter=3, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<RadioButton Content="50" GroupName="Radius"  IsChecked="{Binding RadiusRadio, Converter={StaticResource Radius}, ConverterParameter=4, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<RadioButton Content="All" GroupName="Radius"  IsChecked="{Binding RadiusRadio, Converter={StaticResource Radius}, ConverterParameter=5, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

As you can see, the convert-parameter defines which radio button is which. When you select one, it is store in your `private int _radiusRadio;`

In your datacontext, you can create your own "converter", to get values you want instead of "1,2,3,4,5" which looks like this for example (note, that this is just optional "best-practice" I am using) >

```
    public int Radius
    {
        get
        {
            if (_radiusRadio == 1)
            {
                return 5;
            }
            if (_radiusRadio == 2)
            {
                return 10;
            }
            if (_radiusRadio == 3)
            {
                return 20;
            }
            if (_radiusRadio == 4)
            {
                return 50;
            }
            if (_radiusRadio == 5)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return 0;
        }            
    }
```